# React Native: Linking.openUrl throwing "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Unable to open URL:"

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a Audio/Video Calling app using React Native. There's a screen in the app where calling happens using WebRTC. Let's call it 'Call' screen. TO show calling notification I am using the package `react-native-callkeep`. Once a user picks up the call, I'm taking him directly to the 'Call' screen. Everything works fine except when I'm trying to take the user to the 'Call' screen.

Here's how I'm doing it:

Inside my AppDelegate.m I have this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
  restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
  return [RNCallKeep application:application
           continueUserActivity:userActivity
             restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

Inside the index.js, I'm calling initCalling before registering the app like this:

```
...
initCalling();

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

And Here's what initCalling does

```
const initCalling = () => {
  const options = {
    ios: {
      appName: 'MyApp',
      includesCallsInRecents: false,
      imageName: 'notification_icon',
      supportsVideo: true,
    },
    android: {
      alertTitle: 'Permissions required',
      alertDescription: 'This application needs to access your Calling Service',
      cancelButton: 'Cancel',
      okButton: 'ok',
      imageName: 'notification_icon',
    }
  };

  RNCallKeep.setup(options);

  function checkCallNotification(message) {
    if (!message.data.callType) {
      return;
    }
    const { threadId, messageKey } = message.data;
    RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(
      message.data.channelId,
      message.data.title,
      message.data.title,
      'number',
      message.data.callType === 'video',
    );
    RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', async () => {
      RNCallKeep.removeEventListener('endCall');
      RNCallKeep.endAllCalls();
      Linking.openURL(message.data.deeplink);
      RNCallKeep.removeEventListener('answerCall');
    });

    RNCallKeep.addEventListener('endCall', () => {
      RNCallKeep.endAllCalls();
      RNCallKeep.removeEventListener('endCall');
    });
  }

  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
    checkCallNotification(remoteMessage);
  });

  messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
    checkCallNotification(remoteMessage);
  });
}
```

When a notification arrives, the call keep starts showing the call screen. Once user picks up the call, Im trying to take him to the 'Call' screen but instead I'm getting this

```
index.bundle?platfor…&minify=false:41712 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Unable to open URL: myapp://call
Error: Unable to open URL: myapp://call
```

on debugging I can see the line `Linking.openURL(message.data.deeplink);` is failing even though the url is correct. And this is happening only in iOS. On Android things are working perfect. Can someone please help me know what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks !